# What is the format of a date in database ? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datetime

This is my code

```js
        Establish_Connection con = new Establish_Connection();
        string Fname    = TxtFirstName.Text;
        string Lname    = TxtLastName.Text;
        string Email    = TxtEmailSingUp.Text;
        string Password = TxtPasswordSignUp.Text;
        string DOBDay   = DDLDay.SelectedValue;
        string DOBMonth = DDLMonth.SelectedValue;
        string DOBYear  = DDLYear.SelectedValue;
        string DOB= DOBYear +"/"+ DOBMonth +"/"+ DOBDay;
        string Gender   = LblGender.SelectedValue;
        string UserName = txtUserName.Text;


        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            conn.Open();

        try
        {
            string constr = "INSERT INTO USERS (UserName,FName,LName,DOB,Gender,Email,Password) VALUES (@UserName,@FName,@LName,@DOB,@Gender,@Email,@Password);";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(constr,conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB",DOB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", Lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", Fname);

             int affectrows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("connection established");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("error" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

It keeps telling me about errors in the DOB, and that I need to convert it to date time type, but when I convert it using `Convert.ToDateTime()`, it still gives me errors. In the database the type is `DateTime`, anyone can help me with this?

Comment: what value you have in your DOB field ?

Comment: I have a three drop down lists day , month, and year, and the value of them are  numbers, but in a string,  i put them all in DOB

Comment: replace `/` with `-` and try for example 
(`string DOB= DOBYear +"-"+ DOBMonth +"-"+ DOBDay;`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing something like this:

```
DateTime DOB= new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(DOBYear), Convert.ToInt32(DOBMonth), Convert.ToInt32(DOBDay));
```

`AddWithValue` will then work properly because the value is a valid `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Kamal's code is correct.

Databases usually store Date/Time as a number, the integer portion of which is the number of days since some start date and the decimal the number of milli/micro/seconds since the start of the day. This is usually totally transparent to anyone using it and should not be counted on.

Depending on the database a number of string formats might be recognised. SQL Server, for instance probably won't recognise the format you gave it, but will recognise YYYY-MM-DD. The various forms of DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY can be a problem and I prefer to never use them. I usually use DD MMM YYYY (e.g. '28 Mar 2015') when I'm using strings to represent dates, however in C# since it has a perfectly good DateTime type built in which AFAIK all database drivers understand I use that.